# Return values from rows in a 2d array with a specific value - list results in HTML inside Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to list three values from each row that contains a specific value in the "Status" column within coded HTML inside a Google Script function.  When I run the sendDailyDigest function below, it times out.  I am assuming a have some type of error in the for loop inside the html message variable, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am relatively new to scripting and would be grateful for someone pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you!

```
function sendDailyDigest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(PRIMARY_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = getRowsData(sheet);
  // Count how many requests are awaiting approval
  var numSubmitted = 0;
  for (var i = 2; i < lastRow; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange(i, getColIndexByName("Status")).getValue() == "SUBMITTED") {
      numSubmitted++;
    }
  }
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
  + "<P>" + "The following requests await your approval."
  + "<P>" + "\xa0"
  + "<P>" + "<table><tr><td><b>Request ID</b></td><td><b>Requested By</b></td><td><b>Start Date</b></td></tr>"
    // List each request pending approval
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
      var row = data[j];
      row.rowNumber = j + 2;
      if (row.status == "SUBMITTED") {
          "<tr><td>" + row.rowNumber + "</td><td>" + row.username + "</td><td>" + row.firstDay + "</td></tr>"
      }
    }
  + "</table>"
  + "</HTML></BODY>";
  GmailApp.sendEmail('username@domain.com', numSubmitted + 'Leave Requests Awaiting Approval', '', {htmlBody: message});
}

function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(PRIMARY_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code reused from Reading Spreadsheet Data using JavaScript Objects tutorial //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to all the cells except those in the first row
//       or all the cells below columnHeadersRowIndex (if defined).
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious error I see right now is that you are using the `.getLastRow()` method, which always times out, even if your code is functional.  Instead, try using `.getMaxRows()`. I used to use the `.getLastRow()` method at first, but then realized that it doesn't work for some reason. When I used the `.getMaxRows()` method, the `for` loop did not time out on me.